# Determine the Cloud Platform Hosting a VM

Tags: shell-script, cloud

I need to execute commands conditionally based on the cloud a VM lives in.

How can I create a dynamic variable that sets the cloud for a script to test for this value?

Answer (score 0):

The following has been tested on VMs in ***AWS***, ***Azure*** & ***Digital Ocean*** and known to work correctly ***as of 20191106***:

```
CLOUDPLATFORM="$(dmesg | grep DMI | grep -o 'amazon\|Microsoft\|DigitalOcean')"
```

Obviously this is very tweakable; hope this saves you time-